# cmake can't find header file?

Tags: c++, cmake

I am not sure I understand why I am having this problem..
but cmake seem to have some problems with finding the header file located in a different project.

tree view of my system:

```
tree
.
├─ build
├─ CMakeLists.txt
├─ src
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── database
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   ├── database.cpp
│   │   └── database.h
│   ├── match
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   ├── match.cpp
│   │   └── match.h
│   ├── record
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   ├── record.cpp
│   │   └── record.h
│   └── spectogram
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       ├── spectogram.cpp
│       └── spectogram.h
└── main.cpp
```

I’ve included the directory to the project which header files I am interested in, and also added the path in my 
target_inlcude_directories. The problems is my database.h cannot see record.h.

database/CmakeLists.txt:

```
project(database)
MESSAGE(“In database CMAKELIST”)


#
# Build static library
add_library(database database.cpp database.h)
include_directories(${record_SOURCE_DIR} ${spectogram_SOURCE_DIR})

target_compile_features(database PUBLIC cxx_defaulted_functions)
target_include_directories(database PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${record_SOURCE_DIR} ${spectogram_SOURCE_DIR})
```

record/CMakeList.txt:

```
project(record)
MESSAGE( “In record CMAKELIST” )
# Include externalproject {portaudio} if lib/portaudio don't exist.

INCLUDE(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(project_portaudio
    GIT_REPOSITORY      https://git.assembla.com/portaudio.git
    PREFIX              lib/portaudio
    UPDATE_COMMAND      ""
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND   <SOURCE_DIR>/configure --enable-cxx
    BUILD_IN_SOURCE     0
    BUILD_COMMAND       make
    INSTALL_COMMAND     sudo make install
)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(project_portaudio BINARY_DIR)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(project_portaudio SOURCE_DIR)

SET(portaudio_lib_dir "${BINARY_DIR}/lib/.libs")
SET(portaudio_inc_dir "${SOURCE_DIR}/include")

add_library(record STATIC record.cpp record.h AudioFile.cpp AudioFile.h)

add_library(portaudio STATIC IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(portaudio PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "${portaudio_lib_dir}/libportaudio.so")

set_property(TARGET portaudio APPEND PROPERTY
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${SOURCE_DIR}/include)

add_dependencies(portaudio project_portaudio)     # Not sure if this is allowed for imported targets though

find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
find_package(ALSA REQUIRED)

IF(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "Linux")
   SET(EXTRA_LIBS rt asound jack)
ENDIF(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "Linux")

#
# this makes sure we have compiler flags that allow class::class() = default (>= C++11)
target_link_libraries(record PUBLIC  ${EXTRA_LIBS} ${ALSA_LIBRARIES} portaudio Threads::Threads )
target_compile_features(record PUBLIC cxx_defaulted_functions)
target_include_directories(record PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${project_portaudio})
```

The weird part is that it sometimes is able to compile, and other times it get stuck with this not able to find the header?

what could the problem be?

Comment: to me it seems like spectogram_SOURCE_DIR and record_SOURCE_DIR are not defined (empty) so it is not including it. Try to just do include_directories(include) to inlcude the "include" folder.

Comment: `... also added the path in my target_inlcude_directories.` - Aren't the variable `record_SOURCE_DIR`, which you think to contain directory with `record.h` file, comes as "record" [project's variable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/PROJECT-NAME_SOURCE_DIR.html)? If so, it is not visible from the "database" project because of CMake scoping rules. You may check variable's content with `message()` call.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I run cmake on the most outer, so all CMakeList should be able to see each other. And the `message()` the path does  print out the path. 

@maetulj The variable should exist. 

It does compile sometimes, I guess it has be something with the order.. but its just weird when what it complains about is a header it cannot find.

Comment: `I run cmake on the most outer, so all CMakeList should be able to see each other.` - Actually, "normal" variables defined in one sub-`CMakeLists.txt` are not visible in other sub-`CMakeLists.txt`. Have you tried `message()` call in `database/CMakeLists.txt`? In any case, as you want the header from `record` subdirectory, you probably want to **link with** `record` library, are you? If so, `target_include_directories` call in `record` subdirectory (which you already have) ensures **propagating** include directories to any library's user.

Comment: @Tsyvarev hmm... i just deleted my build folder and ran cmake,  which first time gave me error saying that it didn't know, and the second time did it know it.

Comment: if it helps... i've uploaded the complete code in GitHub.. 

https://github.com/Miail/soundcloud

@Tsyvarev